# Which facsimiles of Codex Vaticanus (B) are extant?

Tags: greek, manuscript

I want to compare the various facsimiles made of [Codex Vaticanus](http://digi.vatlib.it/view/MSS_Vat.gr.1209) (uncial manuscript B) to each other in a few places. **However I want to know which various ones have been made in the past** *and it would be a bonus if they are available online to view*. (I've found a few as you can see from the links.)

The problem is that Wikipedia states the following ones are available:

> Facsimile editions of the codex
>
> Tischendorf, Constantin von (1867). [Novum Testamentum Vaticanum](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum00tisc#page/n3/mode/2up). Lipsiae: Giesecke & Devrient.
>
> Vercellonis, Carlo & Giuseppe Cozza-Luzi (1868). [Bibliorum Sacrorum Graecus Codex Vaticanus](http://www.csntm.org/Manuscript/View/GA_03). Roma.
>
> Bibliorum Scriptorum Graecorum Codex Vaticanus 1209. Milan. 1904–1907.
>
> Bibliorum Sacrorum Graecorum Codex Vaticanus B. Roma: Istituto Poligrafico e Zecca dello Stato. 1999.

Yet earlier on in the article they also speak of a facsimile made by Cardinal Angelo Mai as being the first ever done.

> Cardinal Angelo Mai prepared the first typographical facsimile edition
> between 1828 and 1838, which did not appear until 1857, three years
> after his death, and which was considered unsatisfactory.[106] It was
> issued in 5 volumes (1–4 volumes for the Old Testament, 5 volume for
> the New Testament).

Comment: The Wikipedia listing looks pretty complete to me. Also, **not** a facscimile, but you might want to compare H.B. Swete's *[The Old Testament in Greek according to the Septuagint](https://archive.org/details/texts?and[]=swete%20%22Old%20Testament%20in%20Greek%22)* which appeared in three volumes, and follows B where it's available.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be what you want:

https://archive.org/details/CodexVaticanusbFacSimile